# TMS - properly delete dbPlanner1 Item

Tags: delphi, tms

I tried :

```
procedure TForm4.Delete1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
dbPlanner1.FreeItem(dbPlanner1.Items.Selected);
end;
```

But I end up with a sql wait cursor.It deletes the item but I need to click somewhere else to get rid of it. Hitting DEL on keyboard deletes without that cursor. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you asked TMS?

Comment: I did ...waiting for the answer ...

Comment: I don't really see the point of this post in that case. Let TMS do their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this with a popupmenu menuitem then close the menu :

```
procedure TForm4.Delete1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
dbPlanner1.FreeItem(dbPlanner1.Items.Selected);
ItemPopup.CloseMenu;
end;
```